# Let's simplify terms

Tags: discussion

According to [Podcast #88](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/podcast-88/), the trilogy isn't considered part of Stack Exchange. It means
I was wrong all this time. Why make them so special? Why not get rid of terms like trilogy and Stack Exchange 2.0? This is all evolutionary baggage, and why make the new guy go wonder where the hell the `2.0` label comes from, or why there is a thing called `The Trilogy`. All these things should all be called **Stack Exchange sites**, even if SO (and SU+SF) are all so much bigger.

Comment: The distinction is, SO, SE and SU were not community conceived and vetted. There was no area51 at that time. They were simply launched. The Trilogy (well, SU/SF) were the first experiments to see how well the system would work outside of programming Q&A. I think they deserve a bit of historical value, and the distinction isn't really that confusing. However, since (iirc) all of the SE 1.0 sites are gone, or converted .. it does simplify things a bit to just call them Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Someone who cares about history of these sites will look it up elsewhere (blog, wikipedia, ...). No one else should be forced to use these terms and distinctions in their daily usage. Why should users 5 years from now care that there was a Trilogy and then there was Area51, unless they cared.

Comment: @Tim: FYI [draw3cards.com](http://draw3cards.com/) still exists as an SE 1.0 site. :)